# java array of multiline strings has length but no data

Tags: java, arrays, string

```
        File file = new File("/home/user/Desktop/linux/myString.txt");

        StringBuilder fileContents = new StringBuilder((int) file.length());
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(file);

        String lineSeparator = System.getProperty("line.separator");

        try {
            while (scanner.hasNextLine()) {
                fileContents.append(scanner.nextLine() + lineSeparator);
            }
            line2 = fileContents.toString().trim();
        } finally {
            scanner.close();
        }

        int location = 0, i = 0;
        String[] newLine2 = line2.split("mySearch"); // Spliting my code to smallers parts
        System.out.println("Times found: " + (newLine2.length - 1) + ".");// Gives the correct answer, it does find the search term
        boolean foundMyWord = false;
        for (i = 0; i <= newLine2.length - 2; i++) {
            int topA = 0, a = 0;
            String text = newLine2[i].replaceAll("[\r\n]+", " ").toString().toLowerCase().trim();
            int size = text.length();
            System.out.println("text size= " + size);// Returns 0

            topA = text.indexOf("notYourLine");//If the segment has this word inside,my word isnt located in it
            a = text.indexOf("neitherInThisSegment");//If the segment has this word inside,my word isnt located in it

            if ((topA <= 0) || (a <= 0)) {
                foundMyWord = true;
            }
            i++;
            System.out.println("Lines= " + i);
            if (foundMyWord == true) {
                location = i;
                System.out.println("The word was inside segment = " + location);
                break;
            }
        }
```

The array has the correct length,in my example 35, but when i try stuff like String myText=newLine2[i] my String remains empty, String myText=newLine2[i].toString(), doesnt help either.

I need to split my code to segments, each segment should start from where my cde finds "mySearch" and should end at the end of the file, or when the next segment starts.

When this is done I need to search this segments to find the one without "notYourLine" or "neitherInThisSegment"

Thanks a lot for your time, my primary language isnt english, neither have I lived in an english speaking country, so sorry if this text is confusing.

Comment: There are quite a few errors in your code. Rather than pointing out each one, I suggest you use an interactive debugger and step through your code examining the variables at each point. You'll soon find your errors and learn how to solve these sorts of problems at the same time.

Comment: I haven't used Scanner before, but a ``new BufferedReader(new InputstreamReader(...)).readline()`` will probably be a suitable equivalent?

Comment: Yes.  You are right.

Comment: I would suggest you to debug by putting a `system.out.println(newLine2[i])` before `String text = newLine2[i].replaceAll("[\r\n]+", " ").toString().toLowerCase().trim();
            int size = text.length();`
Add System.out.println(text) after replacing as well

Comment: @sprinter I want to point out that this is a snippet of my code.

Comment: Could someone please explain, why when i get the correct length, which i guess means it read the correct txt,i cant get any data from the array? thank you

Comment: @GeorgeChatzikyriakou try taking out your 'replaceAll' - I suspect you'll find you do have text in your array. Alternatively, trying printing out the text (as per comment from Shreyas)

Comment: @GeorgeChatzikyriakou One other thing is try to break down the problem into the essential parts, this will help identify the real culprit. The other code can be brought back in afterwards.

Comment: The code was correct, the problem was trying to get the array item [0]. for some reason split does not add data to newLine2[0].